# XSS injection php form firefox

Tags: forms, security, web, firefox-addon, xss

I ran XSS me on firefox to test one of my scripts but I'm getting the following message:

`The character was found unencoded in the result page with ; / and \ symbols.`

The script passes all tests. What does this imply?

Comment: PS: [XSS Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/xss-me/) is a Firefox addon.

Comment: Yes but the message "The character was found unencoded in the result page with ; / and \ symbols." was a little confusing

Comment: I'm just pointing that out to the visitors in case they haven't heard about it.

Comment: Ok, Is it something you are familiar with? If so, what does it mean when it says the characters are unencoded?

Answer (score 2):

This is stating that its possible to write a ;, / or \ to the page without being molested.  These characters could lead to xss,  but probably not.   XSS might look something like this:

```
var "some_value\\""; alert(1)//
```

Usually you just care about angle brackets: `<script>alert(1)</script>`

Comment: I assumed mysql_entities gets rid of this or is that not the case?

Comment: @Jms Bnd what does mysql have to do with xss?

Comment: @Jms Bnd no it does not.  `htmlspeicalcars($var,ENT_QUOTES);` will